# fb:login-button attribute event api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm new to the facebook platform and i see a lack in the documentation (as if i think so).

Is there a place where i can find all the event and attributes i can use for fb:login-button tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/